# X11: how to make a window move after another?

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xorg

I have two top-level windows, win1 and win2.

I want to make win2 follow win1 when win1 is moved so that the position of win2 relative to win1 (I'll call that `relpos`) stays constant. IOW, sticky windows!

My idea was to move win2 in the ConfigureNotify of win1. To do that I need to know the `relpos`.

I can get (and store) relpos in win2's ConfigureNotify when win2 is moved.

The problem is that win2 gets ConfigureNotify both when moved by the user and when moved programmatically. Is there a way to distinguish between the two cases?

If there isn't, the whole approach is a fail, and so the next question is: is there another way?

Thanks.

NOTE: I can't just set a "moving_programmatically" flag, move the window and then check the flag on ConfigureNotify because X is asynchronous (one of its biggest warts - many consider this a feature) and there's no guarantee when and how many ConfigureNotify events I get. Try doing this and move win1 too fast and see how win2 lags behind.

Comment: You are moving it programmatically so you know when this happens...

Comment: @n.m. yes, I could do that if X would've been synchronous like any sane API (winapi/cocoa). I added a clarification note.

Comment: if you're wondering why this problem never occurs when moving child windows (eg. with elastic layouts) it's because there's no ambiguity between who moved the window there because child windows can't be moved/resized by the WM, only by the app.

Comment: I wonder now why it makes a difference who has moved the window. Relative offset is relative offset, regardless. In case it does make a difference to you anyway, when you move a window, you know *where* you move it, so you know which ConfigureNotify to ignore.

Comment: because when I move win2 I have to store the relpos, but when I move win1 I have to move win2 based on relpos (which triggers ConfigureNotify for win2 which changes relpos etc).

Comment: "when you move a window, you know where you move it, so you know which ConfigureNotify to ignore" - can you expand on that?

Comment: `when I move win1 I have to move win2 based on relpos` that's right. `which triggers ConfigureNotify for win2 which changes relpos` that's also right. `etc` where's the "etc"? It changes relpos and that's it. You do precisely nothing.

Comment: well that's the problem: when ConfigureNotify is triggered for win2 from a programmer-induced move, it _shouldn't_ change relpos because win1's position is _undefined_ at that time because X is asynchronous. That's why you save relpos when win2 is moved in the first place, so you can fixate it and use it later when win1 is moved.

Comment: if what you say would work, you wouldn't even need to save relpos when win2 is moved, you could just save the previous position of win1 and compute the delta between win1's prev. pos. and current pos and move win2 by that delta. An easier solution but again, a wrong one in an async environment.

Comment: see http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2015-August/057548.html for another example of how mixing queries with commands in an async environment doesn't work as expected

Comment: `because win1's position is undefined at that time` and this is different from user-induced moves how? In short, have you tried this? If yes, and it doesn't work as expected, show the code.

Comment: The example you cite has nothing to do with your case. Your operations are all idempotent *and* atomic. Got a ConfigureNotify on win1? Move win2. Got a ConfigureNotify on win2? Update relpos. That's it.

Comment: "and this is different from user-induced moves how?" -- because when the user moves win2, win1 is usually fixed -- unless a user has two mice :) yes of course I've tried this, how else could I have figured all this out? my code is in Lua (this is the project: https://github.com/luapower/nw) and I think you want a piece of C and makefile.

Comment: @n.m. with all due respect, let's drop this. you can even downvote the question if it makes you feel better, but I don't think you can help me.

Comment: I just don't understand your problem, let's leave it at that.

Comment: well it seems that you're skeptical that there is a problem in the first place -- now granted, it's a subtle problem, and a knee-jerk reaction would be to dismiss it offhand. Now you seem to know your way around X, why don't _you_ try it and _post an answer_ in classical SO fashion. Either you prove me wrong, I accept your answer and I learn something new, or you understand the problem and you learn something new. It's a win either way.

Comment: also, if you want even more proof, try opening up a menu on a window, and while the menu (which is a separate window) is open, try moving the window. You'll notice that the window doesn't want to move while the menu is open. This is how they "fixed" it.

Comment: I have made a small program that does what you say it should do, by the method I describe, and it works. http://pastebin.com/R37GTs5r One caveat is that you cannot simply feed the deltas to XMoveWindow, because ConfigureNotify gives you your window coords, but XMoveWindow moves *the WM frame* to the specified coords. Or is it the other way around? I can't be bothered to check. I just subtract magic constants 3 and 23 from x and y and it all clicks into place. . Of course in your real program you want to be more robust. I suspect the WM border was your problem in the first place.

Comment: Cool. I ran the program on Ubuntu 10.04, changed offsets to (1, 27) to match the frame extents on that system. Now let's observe the behavior: if you move win1 really really slow it does indeed work (because the events are fired in the order that you would expect). Now move win1 fast this time (jerk it around) and you'll see win2 moving all over the place.

Comment: note how there's two consecutive "W2 old coords..." messages when that happens because well, X can do that to you, being async and all.

Comment: My WM doesn't do that. It only fires ConfigureNotify once, when I stop dragging and release the button. Then the second window snaps to place. Yes, there are two W2 messages, for me the second one always has zero deltas.

Comment: so for you win2 only gets moved after you release the mouse button? so it doesn't even drag while dragging win1? well that is one way to "fix it" I guess :) but anyway in Unity (and I can't ignore Unity can I?) it does what I described. And I suspect that any WM which gives you move messages _while dragging_ will behave this way.

Comment: XMoveWindow won't move your window so that it is fully or partially off screen. What happens is you sending a pair of coordinates and sometimes the window is getting moved to completely different coordinates. The net effect is as if the user has moved it. Try jerking the mouse around but keep it confined in a small area in the centre of the screen. If this works, then Unity sending ConfigureNotify mid-drag has nothing to do with it. You will need to account for movement near screen edges.

Comment: hard to convince aren't ya? :) FYI in Unity, you don't even need to jerk it around much, just very little, and it can be on the center of the screen for 10pixels and it goes off the rails. I suspect that unless you will understand the asynchronous issue (the one here and the one in the mailing list) you'll continue to search for scapegoats :) the reality is that you simply can't build any meaningful program logic with async APIs. As soon as you mix queries with commands you assume synchronous behavior - and sooner or later that will blow in your face.

Comment: I just can't reproduce it. Perhaps post a log so it will be a bit more clear what happens. Anyway, you always can remember if you have an outstanding XMoveWindow. Record when you call it, cancel that state when you get ConfigureNotify with the same coordinates. You may need a queue, or perhaps jusy a counter. When a request is outstanding, don't record new relpos.

Comment: Yeah when you get two events in a row the calculations will be thrown off. The above scheme should take care of this. I'll try to test it on another machine with a different WM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write a window manager for this. The reason for your trouble is that you can't get the "click on win1 title" and "released mouse button over win1" events - the window manager swallows them before your app can see them. With these events, the solution is simple: Get the relative offset when the user clicks on the title bar of win1 and just use this offset while win1 is moved.

Other applications (like LibreOffice) solve this by allowing to drag such windows into the main window (main window grows and child window becomes a palette at the side).

Comment: that's right, but writing a WM is not a solution for an app. Neither is going MDI (most users hate MDI).